# pstricks package not showing ouput despite no erros in tex window

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
This is a line
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,6)
\psline[linewidth=2 pt]{<->}(2,1)(6,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

no line is drawn only the text is shown. How should i proceed

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! How did you compile?

Comment: And where do you view?

Comment: i am compiling with xelatex

Comment: the output file comes as pdf

Comment: i had run the document on miktex for macos and it showed blank document showing page number but with texshop it shows the line